# align my content according to div

Tags: html, css

I have four columns with diff divs, the fourth column is hover. You have to mouseover the fourth column before the input bar shows up. My problem is, since the fourth column is hidden, the data on the first column goes to the fourth column. Help me with this. Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/kerokeroppi/DYvCz/

```
.branch_class {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    padding:0 5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#666;
       }

.branchid_class {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    padding:0 5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#666;
    }

.balance_class {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    padding:0 5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#666; 
              }

.amount_class {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    padding:0 5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#666;
              }
```

and

```
 <div class="branch_class" style="margin-left:10px;">Branch Name</div>
     <div class="branchid_class" style="margin-left:0px;">Branch ID</div>
     <div class="balance_class" style="margin-left:20px;">Balance </div>
     <div class="amount_class" style="margin-left:13px;">Amount</div>
     <form id="topupform-b1" action="" onSubmit="return false">
     <div id="divamount" >
         <div id="branchname" class="branch_class" style="margin-left:7px;">Mail and More-Hermosa</div>
         <div id="branchid" class="branchid_class" style="margin-left:2px;">234</div>
         <div id="balance" class="balance_class" style="margin-left:19px;">234.289</div>
         <input type="string" name="amount" id="amount" style="margin-top:7px; margin-left:15px; background:#FFF;" />
     </div>
```

image:[image: when hover the page is like in this picture]

[image: If not hover, totally screw up.]

Comment: "You have to mouseover the fourth column before it will show up" how are you hiding the column? With CSS?

Comment: Im hiding it bec Im using jquery:http://jsfiddle.net/kerokeroppi/DYvCz/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the jQuery .hide() method. The hide() and show() methods modify the css display property.

.hide or `display:none;`, hides an element does not take up any space when it is hidden. What you want is `visibility:hidden;` which hides an element, but that element will still take up the same space it did before it was hidden.

If you want to do this with jQuery, try this:

```
$(selector).css('visibility', 'hidden');
$(selector).css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Comment: I put it here but its not working:if (flg)
      $(basicmodal).children('form').children('.basic').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  else
   $(basicmodal).children('form').children('.basic').css('visibility', 'visible');
   
 }

Comment: Javascript in general is extra load time so if you can do it with css do it that way, so do display none and then on hover display block

Comment: this is the main prob:I have four columns with diff divs, the fourth column is hover. You have to mouseover the fourth column before the input bar shows up. My problem is, since the fourth column is "hidden" (because it will only shows up when hover), the data on the first column goes to the fourth column. which part should I put this? $(selector).css('visibility', 'hidden');
$(selector).css('visibility', 'visible');